# How do I generate a 'live preview' of a textbox?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Just like on SO when typing a question, I see the live version included in a box below the textbox - or on Github, I can simply go to 'preview' without saving the record, how do I achieve that with Rails?

Assume I have a `Question` model, that has an attribute of `body` that I want to see a live preview (either character by character or by pressing a `preview` button that shows it).

Comment: Ahhh...ok...that approach does make sense and is kinda what I was going for.

Answer (score 0):

in HTML you can put this:

```
<% if params[:preview_button] %>
 <%= textilize @project.description %>
<% end %>
```

...

```
<%= submit_tag 'Create' %>
<%= submit_tag 'Preview', :name => 'preview_button' %>
```

*# => params = { “preview_button” => “Preview” ....* - you will see;

```
def create
 @project = Project.new(params[:project])
 if params[:preview_button] || !@project.save
   render :action => 'new'
 else
   flash[:notice] = "Successfully created project."
   redirect_to project_path(@project)
 end
end
```

You can rewrite create action, add ajax to form preview by putting remote: true

i try to show main idea.